# Environment variable also getting printed

Tags: bash, shell

While typing any commands one of my environment variables also gets printed.

```
[root@appdynamics home]# ls
ls
192.168.71.2  192.168.71.50  karti  lost+found  postgres
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
```

How can I solve it for all the commands it is getting printed?

Shell type:Bash

This is what the output of prompt command and prompt vars

```
[root@appdynamics home]# echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
printf "\033]0 %s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"


[root@appdynamics home]# echo $promptvars    
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
```

## /etc/bashrc:

```
# are we an interactive shell?
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ -z "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ]; then
    case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
        fi
        ;;
    screen)
        if [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen ]; then
            PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
        else
            PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        [ -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default ] && PROMPT_COMMAND=/etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-default
        ;;
      esac
  fi
  # Turn on checkwinsize
```

Comment: This is what i am getting `printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"`  along with output for any commands

Comment: It's still very unclear what the issue is here. Do you have files with interesting names? Is the `printf` displayed after every command? Check your shell init scripts for errors when setting `PS1` and/or `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: to Kusalananda's point, what is the value of $PROMPT_COMMAND ? At a guess, you're trying to set a custom PS1 prompt but got some quotes/backticks wrong

Comment: Kusalanada, not with `ls` eventhough i am giving the command as `cd` or any other commands i am getting the possible results along with that i am getting this line `printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"`

Answer (score 5):

```
printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
```

This comes when you use the command `bash -v`. To get rid of it give the `exit` command.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently something is wrong in your prompt settings. Check your shell configuration file; that's `.bashrc` for bash, `.kshrc` for ksh, `.zshrc` for zsh (always in your home directory). It's also possible that the configuration is in some system-wide file like `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/zshrc`. It's also possible that the configuration is misplaced, e.g. in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`.

What you're seeing as the prompt looks like a command that's meant to be executed by the shell to construct the prompt. Maybe this is bash and someone wrote `PS1='printf …'` meaning `PROMPT_COMMAND='printf …'`. But that's only one possibility among many. Check the configuration files to see how the `PS1` variable is defined, and other shell-dependent settings, such as the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable and the `promptvars` option in bash.

If you can't figure it out, post your shell configuration files. And be sure to say which shell you're using! If you don't tell us exactly what's in your configuration, we can only speculate.

Comment: Gilles,I have updated the mentioned variables output.Do you want me to post my configuration files too(bashrc,/etc/profile,~/.bash_profile)

Comment: @karthikraj Yes. The problem is not in the part you posted. Post the whole files.